# C# class for storing bytes as a stream

Tags: c#

I want an stream like class where I can store data in a format of my own.

I decide what I store in a particular position of the stream.

For example I will use the first two bytes of the stream to store a long integer n. And in the next n bytes I will store a particular string. After that a name in unicode.... etc.

I checked the stream class but it seems to be an abstract class not a class built to handle byte streams. Which is the class for this.

I have considered byte array. But is there a better class (i have to manually split a long into 8 bytes in that case)

So is there a builtin class specialized for my requirement?

Comment: MemoryStream class

Comment: or BinaryReader, BinaryWriter for files

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of streams as accessors for persisted objects. The stream class is designed to be an interface for more specific implementations.  For example, a [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) object is an accessor for reading/writing a file.  If you just need to store data in memory, take a look at the [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the System.IO.Stream-like class for the stream, and the BitConverter class for converting non-string values, Encoding for converting strings into byte sequences, possibly BinaryFormatter depending on usage.

The stream class can either inherit System.IO.Stream or simply wrap it, depending on how you intend to use it.

For the record, you should not be manually splitting your numbers - leave that to the proper implementations in the framework. Also a long is 8 bytes, not bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily store a class or any other object in binary format, look into object serialization 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

Comment: well that is my ultimate goal. To store and regenerate a simple class, but there are thousands of such instances I have to process in a single session. So I thought it would be too expensive computationally, RAM usage and also data usage when communicating with server (data is store in a server that is accessed via internet by all the users using my app). So I thought of implementing it in my way to optimize.

Comment: You should include details like that in your question, because there might be better ways of doing it. Compressing the data before sending it can save a lot of the traffic.